# use getopt to obtain multiple options

Tags: c, getopt

Here is my problem, I wrote a program `a.exe`, it can take several options, like `"r:e:m:"`.
`r:` and `m:` can't appear together, which means they run totally different tasks inside `a.exe`. And `e:` is an optional option, if it shows up, then it should be with `r:`.

How should I implement this logic with `getopt`?

Comment: https://www.whathaveyoutried.com ?

Comment: Getopt has no way to do this. Client code will have to do what you want to be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to manually check for incompatible options. For example, when you see the `-r` option you set a flag saying "`-r` is found", if you then see the `-m` option you check to see if the "`-r` is found" flag is set, and print an error message telling the user about it.

Comment: That's what I did, but I want to know if better approach there is.

Comment: @Alcott Not really, the argument parser in`getopt` is very basic and doesn't handle anything else.